# Date class and Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp

In entity class I have field publicationDate which has java.util.Date type. When I get data from database with hibernate I pass it to JSP page to print publicationDate but I have not only day, month, year but also time. Is it possible to pass to JSP page Date object only with day, month, year? Or should I use another class not java.util.Date?

Comment: I suggest you use [JodaTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) in combination with [Jadira](http://jadira.sourceforge.net/) if you want a good date time framework.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 2 ways of doing it.
Changing the date inside java, using the SimpleDateFormat class.

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

String dates=formatter.format(mydate);
//mydate is your date object
```

In JSP, you'd like to use JSTL  for this. Assuming that ${bean.date} returns java.util.Date, here's how you can use it:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
...
<fmt:formatDate value="${bean.date}" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" />
```

Answer (score 0):

No don't need to change the Date object. Use `SimpleDateFormat` and parse the date object as per your need.

Answer (score 0):

The [answer by BlueMoon92](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21367216/642706) is correct.

## Joda-Time

But as the comment by Tom Verelst says, you'd be wise to avoid the java.util.Date, j.u.Calendar, and java.text.SimpleDateFormat classes. They are notoriously troublesome.

Instead use either the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library, perhaps in conjunction with the [Jadira](http://jadira.sourceforge.net/) library for integration with Hibernate as mentioned in Tom's comment. Or, in Java 8 you can use the new java.time.* package, defined by JSR 310 and inspired by Joda-Time.

You can easily convert between a java.util.Date and a Joda-Time [`DateTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html), to and fro.

Joda-Time offers a rich variety of ways to represent a DateTime as a formatted string. If you know the users Locale or preferences, you can localize the output. Search StackOverflow for many examples using words such as: joda, date, format. I chose one of those many ways in my example below. By default, Joda-Time outputs strings in standard [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, also seen below.

## Example Code

Using Joda-Time 2.3.

```java
java.util.Date myDate = new java.util.Date();

// Specify a time zone rather than rely on default.
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Paris" );

// Convert a java.util.Date object to a Joda-Time DateTime object.
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( myDate, timeZone );

// Factory to create a format from a two character style pattern.
// The first character is the date style, and the second character is the time style. 
// Specify a character of 'S' for short style, 'M' for medium, 'L' for long, and 'F' for full. 
// A date or time may be ommitted by specifying a style character '-'. 
String output = DateTimeFormat.forStyle("M-").withLocale( Locale.FRANCE ).print( dateTime );

java.util.Date backToDateAgain = dateTime.toDate(); // Convert to-and-fro.
```

Dump to console…

```java
System.out.println( "myDate (tells a lie, actually no time zone): " + myDate );
System.out.println( "dateTime: " + dateTime );
System.out.println( "output: " + output );
```

When run…

```
myDate (tells a lie, actually no time zone): Sun Jan 26 15:48:24 PST 2014
dateTime: 2014-01-27T00:48:24.391+01:00
output: 27 janv. 2014
```